# Boolean does not set back to true

Tags: unity-game-engine, boolean

I have a boolean variable in my game that I use to control how many times a NPC can move each turn. It's a tactical RPG. The NPC can move just once per turn. The boolean is called **canMoveNPC** and it's initialized as true. Then, when the NPC reaches his destination, I set it to false.

However, when I pass the turn to the human player, I want this variable to be true again, because in this way, the NPC is able to move again when it's his turn. But it doesn't set back to true, it stays as false. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This code I use to move the NPC and set the variable to false:

```
ublic void Move()
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < mov.NPCS.Length; i++)
         {
             if (!Physics.Raycast(Sherrif.transform.position, Sherrif.Left_Right, out Sherrif.hitRight) || Sherrif.hitLeft.transform.tag != "Human")
             {
                 if (mov.gameManager.NPCTurn && canMoveNPC )
                 {
                     mov.NPCPlayer = mov.NPCS[2];
                     mov.NPCS[2].GetComponent<NPC>().isNPC = true;
                     IsMoving = true;

                     this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.transform.position, targetPosition, velocity * Time.deltaTime);
                 }

                 if(this.transform.position == targetPosition)
                 {
                     mov.NPCS[2].GetComponent<NPC>().isNPC = false;
                     IsMoving = false;
                     canMoveNPC = false;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

And here, I have a game manager that I use to control the turns and set the variable to true again. I use the code bellow when the NPC passes his turn:

```
else if (mov.gameManager.playerTurn == 2)
         {
             mov.gameManager.playerTurn = 1;
             mov.gameManager.NPCTurn = false;
             mov.gameManager.HumanTurn = true;
             mov.TurnEnd();
             mov.interfaceManager.ChangeTurn();

             for (int i = 0; i < mov.NPCS.Length; i++)
             {
                 mov.NPCS[i].GetComponent<NPC>().canMoveNPC = true;

             }
         }
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: This may help.  `MoveTowards` does not overshoot its target so you need to check for "approximately equivalent".  See the `Update` method in Unity's documentation to see how they do it.  The doc description may help as well.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

Comment: But when I print the NPC position and the target position they are the same. Target position is a vector3 that I use to move the NPC to tile which is in front of him.

Comment: Basically it looks ok. I'd use the debugger and first set a breakpoint just after the loop where you set all the flags, then after that place the breakpoint on the point where the flag is set to false. Maybe for some reason you NPC code assumes instantly that its turn is up and it sets it to false again.    You can also go further and use a watchpoint to see when that variable goes back to false. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2019

Comment: I've already tried to use the breakpoint, but I don't know how it works exactly. I think the error occurs when I set to the NPC turn again.

Comment: As I suspected it changes when the human player passes his turn to the NPC turn

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what was happening. The target position wasn't being updated, so it would always be false that variable.

The problem is solved.